# Unable to resolve "fbjs/lib/areEqual" from "node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\createHandler.js"

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-datepicker

I'm building a react-native application with expo, however, I have an error, therefore I'm unable to continue building the application. I even looked for the file in node_modules that is mentioned in the error message. I'm using the react-native-gesture-handler for my screen navigation. If I uninstalled the react-native-gesture-handler and I removed the navigation code would this solve my error? How do I resolve this?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Plan from './screens/Plan';
import Home from './screens/Home';


const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  PlanScreen: { screen: Home },
  HomeScreen: { screen: Plan }
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator/>
    )
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import MyDatePicker from './Components/DatePicker.js'
import ImageSelector from './Components/ImageSelector.js'

export class Home extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: 'input'}
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Plan Name:</Text> 
        <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 0.8}}
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
       value={this.state.text}/>

      <Button style={{ width: 50, alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
      title="Add Plan"
      onPress={() =>
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PlanScreen')}> 
        <MyDatePicker/>
        <ImageSelector/>
        </Button>
        </View>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide me with the overall code?

Comment: @hongdevelop I've added Home.js to my question which contains my overall code.

Answer (score 11):

I just solved this in my project by doing `npm install fbjs`.

[`fbjs`](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs) utils has the desired (and missing) `"areEqual": "fbjs/lib/areEqual",`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a `component` into a `button`. Remove `components`.

**Home.js**

```js
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Plan Name:</Text> 
        <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 0.8}}
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
       value={this.state.text}/>

      <Button style={{ width: 50, alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
      title="Add Plan"
      onPress={() =>
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PlanScreen')} /> 
        </View>
      )
```

OR You can use `TouchableOpacity`

```js
import {
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PlanScreen')} >
        <MyDatePicker/>
        <ImageSelector/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise they were inside my <Button>  component. It hasn't resolved this error but I've changed it.

Comment: I was trying to setup the navigation between the home page and the second page but I don't think it has worked. Do you think the error is related to this since it refers to the react-native-gesture-handler dependency?

Comment: Will TouchableOpacity also cause an error? MyDatePicker seems to be causing an error.

Comment: I have tried using TouchableOpacity instead of Button but this has still resulted in the same error. I have also tried removing MyDatePicker and this didn't fix it either.